# Sandbox. Code Access Security. System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission

Tags: c#, .net, security, .net-assembly, appdomain

I am trying to build a simple minded model. Hosting console application; trusted API assembly and low trust client plugin assembly. For this I created a console app which builds minimum appdomain with minimum permissions, i built a trusted API and signed it, loaded "API" assembly into new domain and called "file writing" method. I expected this call to go thru because as far as I understand if strongly named assembly (signed )loaded into any domain by default it behaves as SecurityCritical.
But to my surprise the assembly method rises an exception System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.

For some reason call to crFile() method results in security exception. Amazing that same call inside constructor of the FileReaderThing class goes smoothly without exceptions.

Please help

Below is the code of Main

```
class Program
{
    const string APIDLLPath = @"C:\prototypes\sandboxes\trustedlib.dll";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PermissionSet restrictedPerms = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
        restrictedPerms.AddPermission( new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));

        AppDomainSetup appDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup
        {
            ApplicationBase = @"C:\prototypes\sandboxes",
        };
        Assembly a = Assembly.LoadFile(APIDLLPath);
        StrongName apiStrongName = a.Evidence.GetHostEvidence<StrongName>();
        AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
            "Sandbox", null, appDomainSetup, restrictedPerms, apiStrongName);

        try
        {
            //object o = sandbox.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(APIDLLPath,
            //                                          "TrustedLib.FileReaderThing");
            ObjectHandle o = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(sandbox, APIDLLPath,
                                                      "TrustedLib.FileReaderThing");
            IFileReaderThing ifl = (IFileReaderThing)o.Unwrap();
            ifl.crFile();
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "exception: a= {0}\nb = {1}", exc.Message, exc.InnerException);
        }

    }
}
```

And this is my simple assembly:

```
**[assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers]**
namespace TrustedLib
{
    public interface IFileReaderThing
    {
        void crFile();
    }
    public class FileReaderThing : MarshalByRefObject, IFileReaderThing
    {
        **[SecuritySafeCritical]**
        public FileReaderThing()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FileReaderThing ctor");
            crFile();
        }
        public void crFile()
        {
            try
            {
                **(new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)).Assert();**
                var file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"c:\katia\troha.txt", true);
                file.WriteLine("troha");
                file.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("exception {0}", exc.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I added a statement (below)  to the security challenged function crFile, added assembly wide attribute AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] and decorated the crFile function with SecuritySafeCritical attribute and everything started to work. I still don't understand why the "assert" call is needed, but it worked

```
                 (new PermissionSet(PermissionState.Unrestricted)).Assert();
```

Comment: I'd recommend to trace/check current domain name whenever particular method is called - it may happen that code runs in different domain than you think... In 2.0 fully trusted code could assert any permission - so any time you need to do something in trusted code like reading file you'd assert that permission, but I think 4.0+ is all different...

Comment: Thank you, Alexei for suggestion. But i check the name of the domain. Both constructor and crFile methods are called in context of "Sandbox" domain